# can not getting two data types in one input function in python:

Tags: python

```
print (how many days do we have in a week?)
print(a:6 \n
      b:7  \n
      c:8)

ques=int(input("enter your answer:"))
print(ques)
```

my question is simple in this case if the user gives "7" so the answer is correct I know but if the user gives "b" rather than "7" this is also correct answer right ? but in input function how to solve the problem I hope you understand my problem

correct explanation AND

Comment: If you expect to accept alpha as well as numeric, then you can't do `int` right off the bat.  You could use `if answer.isdigit():` to tell whether they entered a number or a letter.

Comment: @TimRoberts Calling the `int` constructor is usually a better way than `str.isdigit` to test if a string is convertible to `int`. You just have to put it in a `try` block instead.

Comment: That's really an abuse of exceptions, which are quite expensive.  Exceptions should be used for error conditions, not for data validation.

Comment: @TimRoberts My point is that `str.isdigit` would not account for negative integers, and would match a lot of Unicodes that `int` doesn't accept, and if you want to account for those it would end up a lot more expensive, which is why it is typically recommended to construct an `int` directly in a `try` block so the validation logics inside the constructor would perfectly align with what's expected by `int` itself.

Comment: "²".isdigit() == True but int("²") leads to a ValueError exception. Therefore, str.isdecimal() should be preferred although that's not helpful if input values can be negative

Comment: @Tim EAFP is generally preferred in Python over LBYL…

Comment: I've been coding in Python for 25 years.  I've never heard anyone prefer exceptions for validation.  And the Unicode strange digits and negative numbers are irrelevant to this example.  This is a beginning user.  Let's bring them up to speed one step at a time.

Comment: @TimRoberts Well you've heard it now. A good read: https://realpython.com/python-lbyl-vs-eafp/ Quote: "Well, it seems that Python developers generally tend to favor EAFP over LBYL."

Comment: @TimRoberts In the Python glossary we see EAFP being described as a "common" coding style - i.e., not necessarily preferred. However, I quote "This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements"

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  In real life, you'd want all of this data to be taken from a file or database so you could use the same code for many different questions.

```
answers = { 'a': 6, 'b': 7, 'c': 8 }
print("how many days do we have in a week?")
print("a:6\nb:7\nc:8")

answer=input("enter your answer:")
if answer.isdecimal():
    answer = int(answer)
elif answer in answers:
    answer = answers[answer]
else:
    answer = None

if answer is None:
    print("Answer unrecognized")
elif answer == 7:
    print("Right!")
else:
    print("Wrong, answer is 7")
```

Comment: Surely, answer.isdecimal() would be preferred

Comment: What if the input is "²" ?

Comment: That would be a wrong answer, and would be judged as such by this code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Did you even try? Judging by all the syntax errors in the code you posted, you didn't. Entering "²" would raise `ValueError` after your syntax errors are fixed, which is exactly my point. Demo: https://ideone.com/4eyMlt

Comment: OK, so one of the absolute truths I knew about Python was proven wrong today.  I "knew" that `isdigit`, like the C function of the same name, approved only [0-9].  Not true.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a dictionary of answer options. Accept the user input as a string. Then try to convert to int. If the conversion is successful compare the result against the known correct answer. Otherwise, look up input response in the dictionary. Something like this:

```
question = "How many days are there in a week?"
correct_answer = 7
options = {"a": 6, "b": 7, "c": 8}

print(question)

for t in options.items():
    print("{}: {}".format(*t))

response = input()

try:
    answer = int(response)
except ValueError:
    answer = options.get(response)

if answer == correct_answer:
    print("Correct")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of testing if the user gives a right answer there is no need to convert the answer to an integer in the first place since you are not going to perform any numeric operations.

Put the choice-to-answer mapping in a dict and call its `get` method with a default value to normalize the given answer instead:

```
correct_answer = '7'
options = {'a': '6', 'b': '7', 'c': '8'}
answer = input('How many days are there in a week?')
if options.get(answer, answer) == correct_answer:
    print('Correct.')
```